# passing pointers as arguments to functions

Tags: c++

I need help with understanding how pointers are working in this code below as i am really confused.The code is about finding maximum and the minimum value from a given array.I know that the problem can also be approached by using a structure but i want to understand use of pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int max2,min2,max,min,maximum,minimum;
int Maxmin(int a[],int *max,int *min,int i,int j)
{
    if(i==j)
    {
        return *max=*min=a[i];
    }
    else if(i==j-1)
    {
        if(a[i]<a[j])
        {
            *max=a[j];
            *min=a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            *max=a[i];
            *min=a[j];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int mid=(i+j)/2;
        Maxmin(a,max,min,i,mid);
        Maxmin(a,&max2,&min2,mid+1,j);

    }
    if(*max<max2)
    {
        *max=max2;
    }

    if(*min>min2)
    {
        *min=min2;
    }

}

int main()
{
    int a[]={4,30,2,100,230};
    Maxmin(a,&max,&min,0,4);
    printf("%d %d",max,min);
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean the pointers for `max` and `min` arguments? Do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C* for that. But since you're using C++ (according to your tag) then you don't need pointers at all since C++ have proper references.

Comment: Please don't do it like this `int *max` in C++. Use `int &max` and then int min, max; `Maxmin(..,max,...,min)` As well as replace `*max=max2;` to `max=max2;` in the function body. References are preferred in C++ over the C style, pointers. BTW - pointer is address of variable. I.e. when you putting 'int* max' is acutually same thing to `size_t max` where max is address of int variable in memory, &max - gives you this address from the stack.

Comment: Also, if the `Maxmin` function doesn't return a value, why do you declare it as returning an `int`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude actually it returns an int in one case

Comment: What exactly is your question? You tagged this question with c++ but the code looks like c. You are using raw pointers and `stdio.h`. That's not the c++ way.

Comment: You know more than you think about how pointers work. If I ask you to get the largest dish from the cupboard and put it on the table, you can do it without even thinking about it; "the cupboard" is your array and "on the table" is a pointer to where you should put the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the caller side:

`max` and `min` are int variables.
`&max` and `&min` are the memory addresses for these int variables.

From the callee side:

`int *max` and `int *min` are declared as pointers to int in `Maxmin`. Let's see it as if pointers contain a memory address. Pointers to int contain the memory address of an int variable.

`*max` and `*min` is the way to access the memory address content (dereferencing the pointer). Since you have a pointer to an int, you'll read an int out of that operation.

The key to this code is to know that, if you modify `*max` or `*min` from within `Maxmin`, you will be changing the value of `max` and `min` outside the function, because you're working directly with the memory contents of those global variables.

Comment: when i am calling Maxmin(a,max,min,i,mid) in the else statement why am i not passing it as Maxmin(a,&max,&min,i,mid)??

Comment: @Aayushpeace because `max` and `min` are already pointers (memory addresses). Within the function, they refer to the local parameters, not to the global variables. You can try changing the names of the global variables to `gMax`, `gMax2` and so on for clarity. Note: whereas `max2` and `min2` are global int variables within the function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to differentiate between * , & symbols used for pointers and their usage.

`*` operator Can be used in two ways

1. `*` as can be used to define a pointer 
           Eg. `int * ptr`    This thing will create a pointer and can store the address of type int
2. `*` as Dereference Operator    `printf("%d",*ptr);` prints the value
   who's address the pointer is storing.
   Eg. `int a = 10;`  `int *ptr=&a;` `printf("%d",*ptr)`; Dereference the value of pointer ans prints the value as 10

   `&` in Terms of pointers is used only as address of some variable.

Now , In your code when you use `*max` and `*min` , it refers to the value of pointers used in function max , min , which ultimately refers to global variables as you have passed global variable's address in main function 
And when & is used in function for `&max2` and `&min2` it means address of global variables.

The code might be giving a wrong Output because its comparing the value of all the four global variables that can have a junk value . So its better to initialize your global variables like this `int max=-10000 ,min=10000 ,min2=10000 ,max2=-10000`. This will always give a correct output.

Comment: i am  still confused.In this code https://sapphireengine.com/@/cu18mg i have passed an array to print function which takes a pointer as an argument.Now 'a' is a pointer in the function so how am i able to get the contents of the array without dereferring the pointer?

Comment: Array is a data structure which store data of similar type as well as its name serves as pointer to the address of first index of array . Therefore if you pass array into a function ultimately it's address is passed , hence original value is changed in case of array .